# Transform a String to a command

Tags: java, split

I've written a code that can output a boolean truth table, but im stuck at the point where i can transform a String to the command i need to get an output.

Exp.: 
(!x^y)v(x^!z) ->
(not(x) and y) or (x and not(z) ->

```
or(and(not(rows.get(2)),rows.get(1)),and(rows.get(2),not(rows.get(0))));
```

The last line is the code line that would give me the output i need, with x, y and z stored in an ArrayList of ArrayLists containing Boolean values, the whole line combines various methods with one ArrayList of output which would be my result.

I've thought about splitting a String with substrings and defining brackets as delimiters, as well as using regex for splitting them up, but i dont get to a result that does work.

edit:

Code for Method "and"

```
public static ArrayList<Boolean> and(ArrayList<Boolean> a, ArrayList<Boolean> b){

    ArrayList<Boolean> aAndb = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++){  //iter through rows

        if (a.get(i)&&b.get(i)){     //check if values fulfill conditions
            aAndb.add(true)          //set boolean accordingly
        }else{
            aAndb.add(false);
        }
    }
    return aAndb;
}
```

The output from the obove stated example looks like this

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0  //rows.get(0)

1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0  //rows.get(1)

1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  //rows.get(2)

0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0  //result
```

Maybe i should have used a more obvious example:

(AvB) should transform to

```
or(a,b)
```

or in my case

```
print(or(rows.get(0),rows.get(1)));  //print methode just outputs the result
```

which would result in

```
1 0 1 0 //rows.get(0) -> A

1 1 0 0 //rows.get(1) -> B

1 1 1 0 //Result      -> AvB
```

Comment: Maybe just start all over again, with readable (and debugable) code?

Comment: Please share more of your code, or at least example of the expected input and output.

Comment: The most we can provide at this point is emotional support.

Comment: As I understand, your problem is how to parse a string containing a logical expression. I recommend you read something about parsing. There are wealths to be found on the net. Use your favourite search engine.